# Deploying a Rails app on dreamhost issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, hosting, dreamhost

So I'm at a loss with this one.  My error is:

Missing these required gems: jrails You're running: ruby 1.8.7.72 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8 rubygems 1.3.6 at /home/ryann/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.

I have unpacked jrails in my vendor directory and frozen my local rails environment.  Everything works fine on my local machine.

I am using config.gem 'jrails' in my environment.rb file.

My trace is (sorry for the mess):

```
0 /home/ryann/intercomhq.com/releases/20100709162648/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb 336 in `abort'
1 /home/ryann/intercomhq.com/releases/20100709162648/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb 336 in `check_gem_dependencies'
2 /home/ryann/intercomhq.com/releases/20100709162648/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb 170 in `process'
3 /home/ryann/intercomhq.com/releases/20100709162648/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb 113 in `send'
4 /home/ryann/intercomhq.com/releases/20100709162648/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb 113 in `run'
5 /home/ryann/intercomhq.com/releases/20100709162648/config/environment.rb 20 
6 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb 31 in `gem_original_require'
7 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb 31 in `require'
8 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb 299 in `preload_application'
9 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb 248 in `initialize_server'
10 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 255 in `report_app_init_status'
11 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb 233 in `initialize_server'
12 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 194 in `start_synchronously'
13 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 163 in `start'
14 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb 209 in `start'
15 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 262 in `spawn_rails_application'
16 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb 126 in `lookup_or_add'
17 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 256 in `spawn_rails_application'
18 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb 80 in `synchronize'
19 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb 79 in `synchronize'
20 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 255 in `spawn_rails_application'
21 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 154 in `spawn_application'
22 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 287 in `handle_spawn_application'
23 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 352 in `__send__'
24 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 352 in `main_loop'
25 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 196 in `start_synchronously'
26 /dh/passenger/bin/passenger-spawn-server 61
```

Anyone got any ideas on why I'm still missing a gem when I've unpacked it?

Comment: btw, you can use 'Code Sample' option in editor (picture with zeroes and ones) to make stacktrace look presentable.

Comment: thanks for the tip ... I'll keep that in mind for my next question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in shared hosting. There you usually have common gems repository for all users and local in your home directory for only you. The problem can be solved by specifying correct paths in your config/preinitializer.rb or config/environment.rb

```
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/[username]/ruby/gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
Gem.clear_paths
```

This is path structure on my hosting, you may need to updated it for yours.

**edit**
Checked my sources, you may also need to add this before those lines:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/gem_runner'
```

Comment: no go I got the same error message.  I double checked my path from dreamhost and all checks out.  However, it is still looking in my .gem folder and if I browse to that there is nothing there.  Shouldn't it be looking in my vendor folder?

Comment: So it was a combination of things.  

First I had to follow the directions in this forum

http://forums.site5.com/showthread.php?p=87539

And then I added my GEM_PATH to my environment.rb 

Everything seems to be working.  

Thanks.