# 'Unexpected end-of-file detected' when deploying Rails app to Dreamhost under Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger, dreamhost

I'm relatively new to rails apps, but I've got a rails app thats working locally that I'm trying to deploy to a shared hosting server on DreamHost. I've followed all the wiki's and stackoverflow questions, but an answer for this is still eluding me.

I'm deploying with Capistrano, and I've worked out all the issues to get successful deployments working. However, when I go to access anything that is not a static resource on the site, I am greeted with a 'internal server error' and this error from Passenger:

```
Internal server error
Passenger encountered the following error:
The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected.

Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner::Error
Backtrace:
#   File    Line    Location
0   /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 134 in `start'
1   /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    253 in `spawn_rack_application'
2   /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   132 in `lookup_or_add'
3   /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    246 in `spawn_rack_application'
4   /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   82  in `synchronize'
5   /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   79  in `synchronize'
6   /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    244 in `spawn_rack_application'
7   /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    137 in `spawn_application'
8   /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    275 in `handle_spawn_application'
9   /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  357 in `__send__'
10  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  357 in `server_main_loop'
11  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  206 in `start_synchronously'
12  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server 99
```

I can SSH into the server and manually run 'rails s' to get a server running on port 3000, and everything there works great.

Here's my environment.rb:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
LoLItemDb::Application.initialize!

# potential fix for Dreamhost shared resources
# from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3214748/189292
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/gem_runner'
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/gravitydev/ruby/gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
Gem.clear_paths
```

deploy.rb:

```
user = "XXXXXXXXX"
domain = "XXXXXXXXX.com"
database = "mysql.XXXXXXXXX.com"

set :application, "XXXXXXXXX"
set :rails_env, "production"
set :use_sudo, false

# set rake to be verbose for capistrano
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071126/how-can-i-run-rake-with-trace-within-capistrano
set :rake, "#{rake} --trace"

# here we set a custom paths to commands since on Dreamhost
# servers the user path is a bit different
set :bundle_cmd, "/home/#{user}/.gems/bin/bundle"
require 'bundler/capistrano'

# redirect path for whenever, and use bundler to execute it
set :whenever_command, "/home/#{user}/.gems/bin/bundle exec whenever"
require 'whenever/capistrano'

# configure credentials
set :user, user
set :password, "XXXXXXXXX"

# configure git
default_run_options[:pty] = true                          # Must be set for the password prompt
                                                          # from git to work
set :repository, "git@github.com:XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX.git"  # Your clone URL
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{domain}"
set :scm, "git"
set :scm_passphrase, "XXXXXXXXX"                    # The deploy user's password
set :scm_verbose, true
set :git_shallow_clone, 1

# configure deploy location
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{domain}"

# setup web server
server domain, :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
#server domain, :app, :web
#role :db, database, :primary => true

# for SSH
# see: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Capistrano
set :chmod755, "app config db lib public vendor script script/* public/disp*"

# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

# run the all "LoL" tasks to refresh the database
#after "deploy:restart", "lol:all"

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# for Passenger
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end
```

and GEMFILE:
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'bundler'
gem 'rake'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'haml'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'json'
gem 'whenever'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'rack'
gem 'RedCloth', '4.2.9'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'capistrano'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Most posts seem to suggest the path to gems is incorrect, but I've made every configuration change I can find by searching Google and documentation from Dreamhost. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After messing around with this for quite a while, a couple things led me to a solution. First, when deploying to Dreamhost you need to override your GEM_HOME path in the config.ru like so:

```
# taken from https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-128599.html
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = '/home/USERNAME/.gems'
require 'rubygems'
Gem.clear_paths
```

Additionally, I read the comment from abhas which got me thinking my `Gemfile` was requiring gems I didn't need to specify. Basically, I had added them before to try and mimic my local gem installation, but found I didn't need them all. My final `Gemfile` looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'bundler'
gem 'rake'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'haml'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'whenever'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'capistrano'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

After making these changes, Passenger was happy and found all the gems needed! Thanks to abhas for getting me thinking about changing things in the right area.

EDIT: I'll accept this answer when StackOverflow lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

in your gemfile change this

```
gem 'RedCloth', :require => 'redcloth'
```

it may work

Comment: This led me in the right direction even though it was not the final answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11385960/189292 for what I did to solve this. Thanks for the reply!